# NGINX Url Rewrite for PHP Variable

Tags: nginx, rewrite

How would I go about making a url like:

```
http://example.com/test123
```

go to a url like

```
http://example.com/?code=test123
```

My server runs Nginx, and a lot of the documentation on the web is for Apache.  Im guessing something needs to go in nginx config. Please advise what and where I would need to place code to make this work.

Comment: location = / {
  rewrite ^ http://www.example.com/$arg_code;
}

Answer (score 1):

So in the end I solved it myself. I opened up

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

and went through to find the location section under "server{}"

I changed it to this and it works great

```
location / {
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            #try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            rewrite  ^/(.*)$ /index.php?nginx_rewrite=$1;
            # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
            # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules
    }
```

So I can now go to my url like http://example.com/mystringhere and get it in php using the get method.